# FBLoginView not showing with on StoryBoard

Tags: ios, facebook, storyboard

So, basically I have exactly the same as the FQLHowTo project thats included in the Facebook samples, but I only changed the xib to be a storyboard (since that would be fitting my app better).

The problem I am having, is that the FBLoginView does not show then. When I change it around so it uses the xib, it shows without problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of trial and error (Was stuck with this for a couple of days before posting) I found a solution.
Autosize had set the height of the view to 0...